# Can't Search for downloadable Software Even Though I'm Following Instructions

Tags: gimp

I am trying to download and install Gimp on Ubuntu 22.04.  Instructions state:

1. Open Ubuntu Software (I did that)
2. Search Gimp---???
   This is where the problem is: There is no search window or any other means to search for Gimp.  the "Software & Updates" screen only shows:

Downloadable from the Internet in boldface followed by a list of checkboxes, then a "Download from:" field defaulting to "Server for United States" followed by a box labeled "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD with capability to check a box "Officially supported / Restricted copyrght.  Checking this box does nothing.  How do I search for the program I want to download?

Comment: You're in the wrong app. *Software and Updates* =/= *Ubuntu Software*. Software and Updates is a GUI for settings associated with the packaging system.

Answer (score 1):

"*Open Ubuntu Software (I did that)*"

No, you did not. It's an easy mistake,

Your description seems complete and conclusive: You opened the "Software and Updates" app instead.

Close it. Then go back and try opening Ubuntu Software again. GIMP is available there. Really.